# How to create files/folders in java DynamicWebApplication?

Tags: java, eclipse, jersey, jax-ws

I am using [REST with Java (JAX-RS) using Jersey](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html) to create web-services. 
Now, for my project, I need to create folders at runtime relative to my project.

This is what I did.

```
String str = "<?xml version=1.0><users><user name=\"Taruni\" id=\"501\"></users>";          
File f= new File("helloWorldIndia.xml");
boolean status = f.createNewFile();
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(f);
writer.write(str);
```

Here, the status is returning `true` but file is not visible anywhere in my machine. I have scanned through out my machine. Even then I couldn't find.

What is the proper way to create folder/file? Is it ok in creating folders relative to project? If not what is the alternative?

Comment: Just a side note: did you consider application redeployment? A redeploy may delete all files created inside your project structure. Btw: the file should be available - but relative to your JVMs home directory...

Comment: No. How to handle all those things?

Comment: Fairly simple, do not write into the project directory (everything inside the WAR). Define a data sink (be it a database or file system path).

Comment: Ok fine. But, how to create folder/file? Why its not working if I do with above code? Is there anything wrong my code?

Comment: Did you scan your file system for `helloWorldIndia.xml`?

Comment: Yes, I have scanned for `helloWorldIndia.xml` through out my filesystem. But, I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

> new File("helloWorldIndia.xml").createNewFile()

The file "helloWorldIndia.xml" gets created wherever you are running your program from. In this case your program is being run by the web server. Hence, the file will get created at the path where your web server has **deployed** the web app and **not** where you put the war file at.

Lets assume for now that your web server is jetty. With default config, jetty deploys the war in system's temp folder which is at %TEMP% on windows and /tmp on linux.
In this case if you search the temp folder for "helloWorldIndia.xml", after running your code, you should find the file.

With this said, some servers delete the deployed files when you shutdown the server. A reason for your file not being found on doing a FS scan might be that the deployed folder itself was deleted when you shutdown the server.

To find out where your code is writing the file, add this line at the end of your snippet.

> System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());

This will log the full path where the file was created with your current code.

In case of web apps you should write files to at an *absolute path* of the file system. Writing at relative paths is not safe because if you configure your server to deploy at a different location then previously written files might not be located without changing config/code.

Best way is to make the absolute path of the folder where you want to write the file *configurable* in your code. You can pass the path of folder into which files need to be written -

- As an environment variable (-D property while starting the server).
- As a [servlet config](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletConfig.html) property from web.xml like [this](http://www.javatpoint.com/servletconfig)
- As a configuration entry in the database. Do a DB query at runtime to get the folder's path.
- And many more..

As a note though its not recommended to write files via a web app until its unavoidable. One of the reasons can be transactions. Transactions can't handle file IO automatically. In case a transaction fails and needs rollback, you have to manually handle file writing scenarios.

Comment: @user1046143.. I am running from Eclipse. I donno where it got created. If I give absolute path then its returning `FileNotFound` exception.

Comment: boolean status. See if it is true or not. If not then your file was never even created.

Comment: its returning true. But, I couldn't find file.

Comment: Don't worry too much about this file which you are creating. If its for temp purposes, create it in system temp folder. Otherwise write it to a fixed absolute location like new File("/home/user/path/to/folder"). That is what I am suggesting. And running it from eclipse doesn't mean the web server is eclipse! You must have configured eclipse to start a webserver and deploy your artifacts in it.

Comment: But, if I give absolute path, I am getting `FileNotFound` exception. 
File f= new File("~/Desktop/timesofindia.xml");
I replace the file creation with above code.

Comment: This is because you are using "~". Try giving an absolute path like "/home/user/tilesofindia.xml"

Comment: I did that one also. I am using mac machine. So I used this one. 
"/Users/taruni/Desktop/timesofindia.xml" Even then, `IOException`.. "No such file or directory"

Comment: I don't have much idea about Mac but check out the permissions. Is eclipse starting tomcat as a user which can write to "/Users/taruni/Desktop/timesofindia.xml" location. Check if its the OS permissions problem which are not allowing you to create the file.

Comment: new File("/Users/taruni/Desktop/timesofindia.xml").createNewFile(). Try this from a separate program. If it works for you and your JAX-RS code doesn't then most likely it would be a permission problem.

Comment: How to change the permission? where can I change the permission for my project?